# MVC - jQuery validation does not work on dynamically added elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, validation

I know this kind of issue has been solved many times already, however I am unable to get mine fixed based on solutions provided.

I am building a simple library application. There is a feature to add a copy of a book, which uses jQuery to invoke controller actions and return partial views which are then added dynamically to the DOM.

The last dynamically element added is a form with additional details of a created copy. The ajax call is being triggered when a value of a `DropDownList` (`#AuthorBooksDropDown`) (also added dynamically) changes.

```
$('#authorBooksPlaceHolder').on('change', '#AuthorBooksDropDown', function () {

    var bookId = $(this).val();

    $.get('/Books/AddCopy_RenderDetails/' + bookId, function (data) {

        $('#bookDetailsPlaceHolder').html(data);
        $('#bookDetailsPlaceHolder').slideDown();
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');
});
```

The call invoked the `AddCopy_RenderDetails` action get an entity from a DB based on book `id`, and creates a new copy with certain fields populated.

Controller action:

```
public PartialViewResult AddCopy_RenderDetails(int id)
        {
            var book = db.LibraryBooks.Find(id);

            var newCopy = new Book()
            {
                Author = book.Author,
                Title = book.Title,
                Publisher = book.Publisher,
                CollectionId = book.CollectionId,
                Collection = book.Collection
            };

            return PartialView("_AddCopy_Details", newCopy);
        }
```

The view displays remaining fields which need to be populated.

```
@model CityLibrary.Models.Library.Book

<div class="vertical-separator"></div>

<hr />

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AddCopy", "Books", new AjaxOptions
{
    UpdateTargetId = "bookDetailsPlaceHolder"
}, new { @id = "addCopyForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Author)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Title)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.CollectionId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Collection.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Publisher)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Collection.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Collection.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "" } })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ISBN, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ISBN, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ISBN, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Publisher, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Publisher, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @disabled = "disabled" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Publisher, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.YearPrinted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.YearPrinted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @Value = "" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.YearPrinted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success btn-block" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Even though I have `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');` invoked when the form is rendered (checked in chrome dev tools), validation still happens on the server side upon pressing a submit button as a POST action is being triggered every time. Not to mention that validation errors do not display upon TABing to next field.

Validation attributes are there in form's inputs:

[image]

I also have remote validation which checks whether a entered ISBN is already in the database. Obviously this works on the client side, which in my case simply does not.

Thank you for your time and help.

**EDIT:**

Well, I've added the following to the end of the view:

```
<script>
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');
</script>
```

And it works. I have no idea why triggering it on a function does nothing.

Comment: Just a reminder, check if #authorBooksPlaceHolder is already there in the view and not populated dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. `#authorBooksPlaceHolder` is a static div, initially with `display: none`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is async, and your `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');` line of code is being called before the html has been added to the DOM. Move it to inside the `success` callback

```
$.get('/Books/AddCopy_RenderDetails/' + bookId, function (data) {
    $('#bookDetailsPlaceHolder').html(data);
    $('#bookDetailsPlaceHolder').slideDown();
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');
});
```

Comment: Thank you sir, it solved the issue. Could you tell me why adding `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');` after the closing brackets of `$.get(...)` did not work? Why is it called before, even though it is placed 'after' the call?

Comment: Ajax is asynchronous. That means that its runs while the rest of your code continues to execute, so before the `$.get()` method has had a chance to get the partial view back from the controller, the `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#addCopyForm');` line of code is hit (but the html has not been added at that point).

Comment: As a side note, you should delete your `Ajax.BeginForm()` and use `$.post()` -  the `Ajax.xxx` methods are effectively obsolete and are not even supported in the latest version of MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Try this peace of code

```
    $("form").on("submit", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse($('#addCopyForm'));  // here you need define your form id
            if ($(this).valid())  // use to validate the form
                  {
                //do ajax call
                $.ajax({
                    type: "Post",
                    url: "/Books/AddCopy_RenderDetails/" + bookId,
                     contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",                        
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {                         
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thank you, but I using `Ajax.BeginForm` saved me from inserting all this code. Anyway, this is another way to get it done.